# We're turning 10!

Tags: discussion, community

*Robotics* is turning 10 years old this fall!

Thanks to the whole community for making this a great site to get your robotics questions answered.

The StackExchange blog will feature us along with the other sites turning 10 this fall.  For example: https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/06/27/celebrating-the-stack-exchange-sites-that-turned-ten-years-old-in-spring-2022/.  We need to provide a short blurb about our site.  So if you want to contribute, here are some prompts:

- What have been your favorite or most helpful posts?
- What do you like best about our community?
- What do you come here to learn?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not great with words, but here are some broad strokes:

- find out [why Mars rovers have those weird wheels](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/679/why-are-mars-rovers-so-slow)
- get help [tuning your PID loops](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/167/what-are-good-strategies-for-tuning-pid-loops)
- determine the [DH parameters for your robot arm](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/23019/dh-parameters-of-a-2-dof-rp-robot)
- debug your [ROS nodes](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/3110/ros-best-practices)

The linked questions are pretty highly ranked, so they are pretty old.  Feel free to suggest newer or better threads.  Are there other general topics that come up a lot?  Perhaps Kalman filters / particle filters, or something about quadcopters?